# Jquery mobile "Save as bookmark" button in jquery mobile, for my library book list,

Tags: jquery, mobile, ionic-framework

Good day friends....please help me out in need to make a  "Save as bookmark" button in jquery mobile, for my library book list, where by you can view the bookmarked books in another page or delete them...?

The app contains books and a list view just like a book store where by any book you click on can be bookmarked

Answer (score 0):

Try this small function:

**JavaScript:**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

  //First, set jQuery in no conflict mode, to avoid conflicts with other libraries
  var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
  //Then proceed with code
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#bookmarkme").on("click", function() {
      if (window.sidebar) { // Mozilla Firefox Bookmark
        window.sidebar.addPanel(location.href,document.title,"");
      } else if(window.external) { // IE Favorite
        window.external.AddFavorite(location.href,document.title); }
      else if(window.opera && window.print) { // Opera Hotlist
        this.title=document.title;
        return true;
  }
});
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<a id="bookmarkme" href="#" rel="sidebar" title="bookmark this page">Bookmark This Page</a>
```

EDIT:

IE will show an error if you don't run it off a server (it doesn't allow JavaScript bookmarks via JavaScript when viewing it as a `file://....`